# Método em C# com nome da procedure e outros parâmetros

Tags: c#

Serei o mais breve possível na minha dúvida que é a seguinte: Estou atuando num esquema onde meu programa em C# vai guardando em lista os nomes das procedures e seus respectivos parâmetros que foram executados durante o processo e serão salvos usando o `log4net` numa tabela. Pois bem, criei um método na classe `RequisicaoDTO` que vai guardando o nome da procedure, mas estou tentando passar pra dentro deste método o `for` com os valores dos parâmetros, pois este procedimento vou botar em outros lugares também, segue abaixo tudo que fiz:

Classe:

```
public class RequisicaoDTO
{
    public List<string> procedures = new List<string>();

    public string ProcedureAuxiliar { get; set; }
        
    public List<string> ProceduresAdd(string comando)
    {
        procedures.Add(comando);

        return procedures;
    }
}
```

Primeiro método que o programa executa as informações:

```
public long GerarNumeracaoPI(int tipo, DTO.RequisicaoDTO requisicao)
        {
            var numeroPI = new long();

            //System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

            //string server = builder.DataSource;
            //string database = builder.InitialCatalog;

            using (var scope = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
            {
                using (var comando = db.GetStoredProcCommand("dbo.PR_P_GERA_PROXIMO_NUMERO_PI"))
                {
                    db.AddInParameter(comando, "@TIP_PI", System.Data.DbType.String, tipo);
                    db.AddOutParameter(comando, "@PROXIMO_NUMERO", System.Data.DbType.Decimal, 10);
                    db.AddOutParameter(comando, "@CD_ERRO", System.Data.DbType.Decimal, 10);
                    db.AddOutParameter(comando, "@DS_ERRO", System.Data.DbType.String, 2060);

                    db.ExecuteScalar(comando);
                    
                    var auxNomeBase = comando.Connection.Database;
                    
                    requisicao.ProceduresAdd(comando.CommandText);

                    requisicao.ProcedureAuxiliar = $"Procedure: {comando.CommandText}" +
                                                  $"\nParâmetros: ";

                    for (int i = 0; i < comando.Parameters.Count; i++)
                    {
                        requisicao.ProcedureAuxiliar += $"\nNome:{comando.Parameters[i].ParameterName}, Tipo: {comando.Parameters[i].DbType}, Valor: {comando.Parameters[i].Value.ToString()}, Direção: {comando.Parameters[i].Direction}";
                    }

                    requisicao.procedures.Add(requisicao.ProcedureAuxiliar);

                    if (Convert.ToInt16(db.GetParameterValue(comando, "@CD_ERRO")) != 0)
                    {
                        throw new Exception($"Não fois possível obter número de apólice/endosso: {db.GetParameterValue(comando, "@DS_ERRO").ToString()} ");
                    }

                    numeroPI = Convert.ToInt64(db.GetParameterValue(comando, "@PROXIMO_NUMERO"));

                };

                scope.Complete();
            };

            return numeroPI;
        }
```

Este é o `for` que lê os 4 parâmetros da proc e forma o resultado concatenando os nomes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < comando.Parameters.Count; i++)
{
    requisicao.ProcedureAuxiliar += $"\nNome:{comando.Parameters[i].ParameterName}, Tipo: {comando.Parameters[i].DbType}, Valor: {comando.Parameters[i].Value.ToString()}, Direção: {comando.Parameters[i].Direction}";
}
```

Neste meu método eu passo ao `requisicao.ProceduresAdd(comando.CommandText);` apenas o nome da procedure no método da classe, teria um jeito de acessar os parameters da procedure com C# na minha classe dentro do método ou passar tudo de uma vez? Assim só chamaria meu método em todos os lugares que chamam procs, na `public List<string> ProceduresAdd(string comando)` já troquei `string` comando por `Object` comando, na hora de debugar mostra os objetos mas não rolou o acesso as informações dos parameters.

Resultado ficaria assim no meu método:

```
Procedure: dbo.PR_P_GERA_PROXIMO_NUMERO_PI
Parâmetros: 
Nome:@TIP_PI, Tipo: String, Valor: 2, Direção: Input
Nome:@PROXIMO_NUMERO, Tipo: Decimal, Valor: 2120000110, Direção: Output
Nome:@CD_ERRO, Tipo: Decimal, Valor: 0, Direção: Output
Nome:@DS_ERRO, Tipo: String, Valor: , Direção: Output
```

Obrigado galera, espero ter sido claro, um abraço e agradeço qualquer help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se entendi o problema corretamente, **você precisa ter acesso ao nome e aos parâmetros de uma Stored Procedure em lugares diferentes**. Acredito que a solução mais simples seria passar a variável `comando` para o método (recebendo um [IDbCommand](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idbcommand?view=net-5.0) nele):

```
public List<string> ProceduresAdd(IDbCommand comando) 
{
    // comando.CommandText...
    for (int i = 0; i < comando.Parameters.Count; i++)
    {
        /* ... */
    } 
}
```

Sendo este o caso, a partir da implementação que receber no seu método, terá acesso tanto ao nome do comando com `comando.CommandText` quanto aos seus parâmetros com `comando.Parameters`.

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado Ruan pelo apoio, você esta certo, era só chamar mesmo por parâmetro o DBCommand, foi um grande aprendizado, segue abaixo como ficou meu método:

```
public void ProceduresAdd(DbCommand comando, SqlDatabase database)
    {
            var auxAgrupamento = new StringBuilder();

        
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(database.ConnectionString);

            auxAgrupamento.AppendLine($" Procedure: {comando.CommandText} - ")
                          .AppendLine($" Nome da Base: {builder.InitialCatalog} - ")
                          .AppendLine($" Parâmetros: ");

            for (int i = 0; i < comando.Parameters.Count; i++)
            {
                auxAgrupamento.AppendLine($"Nome:{comando.Parameters[i].ParameterName}")
                              .AppendLine($", Tipo: {comando.Parameters[i].DbType}")
                              .AppendLine($", Valor: {comando.Parameters[i].Value.ConvertToString()}")
                              .AppendLine($", Direção: {comando.Parameters[i].Direction}");
            }

            procedures.Add(auxAgrupamento.ToString());
    }
```

Show de Bola, abraços e espero que isto ajude a quem precisar um dia.